# Angular JS reduce calls to digest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I have an array of elements that I pass from parent controller to child controller through the $scope. I want to add some properties to these elements, such as an instance of MomentJS object so I don't have to keep recreating moment objects when I'm using Underscore's filter function.

Is there a way to safely do this without having to keep adding digest cycles every time I add this property? Can I give a block of statements and tell AngularJS to ignore it?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is synchronous, with few exceptions (notably timers and XHR/DOM events on the client side). Making many modifications to your data in one call will not execute excessive `$digest` cycles, unless you are calling them directly. Have you profiled your code to identify a bottleneck, or are you prematurely optimizing?

Comment: I profiled. It's spending a lot of time making new versions of momentjs objects, so I want to cut that down by attaching the moment object to the object itself. Is this possible without creating a ton of digest cycles? The only other way I'm thinking of doing this is by having a private hash of these. any ideas?